# Counting subdirectories within a directory

Tags: macos, file, command-line, count, terminal

Using Mac OS X 10.8.5.  Figured that doing this on the command line would make the most sense, but other suggestions are welcome.

I have a directory of various backups.  There are about 45 backups here, each an incremental stage run periodically.  The directory structure of each backup dir is the same, but the top/parent directory of each of them has a different name (the time stamp).  Example:

```
2013_9_12_0500/Files/MoreFiles/SomethingElse/Folder/subfolder/morefolders
2013_9_12_0600/Files/MoreFiles/SomethingElse/Folder/subfolder/morefolders
2013_9_12_0700/Files/MoreFiles/SomethingElse/Folder/subfolder/morefolders
2013_9_12_0800/Files/MoreFiles/SomethingElse/Folder/subfolder/morefolders
2013_9_12_0900/Files/MoreFiles/SomethingElse/Folder/subfolder/morefolders
2013_9_12day/Files/MoreFiles/SomethingElse/Folder/subfolder/morefolders
2013_9_13day/Files/MoreFiles/SomethingElse/Folder/subfolder/morefolders
2013_9_14day/Files/MoreFiles/SomethingElse/Folder/subfolder/morefolders
2013_9_10week/Files/MoreFiles/SomethingElse/Folder/subfolder/morefolders
```

etc.

The 'subfolder' directory contains many many subdirectories itself.  I want to count how many sub-directories are within EACH 'subfolder' directory.  Example:

```
2013_9_12_0500/Files/MoreFiles/SomethingElse/Folder/subfolder/  =>  884 subdirs
2013_9_12_0600/Files/MoreFiles/SomethingElse/Folder/subfolder/  =>  1423 subdirs
2013_9_12_0700/Files/MoreFiles/SomethingElse/Folder/subfolder/  =>  540 subdirs
2013_9_12_0800/Files/MoreFiles/SomethingElse/Folder/subfolder/  =>  378 subdirs
```

etc...

I have had some luck with this command:

```
 find ./*/*/*/*/*/subfolder -type d | wc -l
```

The problem is that it only shows me the overall total of ALL 'subfolders' and not the count within EACH individual subfolder.  E.g.  "13543" instead of as listed above.

Yes, I could do this manually one at a time, but were is the excitement in learning something new in that? :)

Thanks,
C

Comment: you basically want a command-line equivalent of sql's `group by`, grouping on the parent folders where the subfolders are. That's not possible with a bare `find|wc` command. you'll need some extra code (sed/awk/perl/whatever) to do that grouping for you.

Comment: Yes, an excellent summarization of what I am trying to achieve.  Bummer that will involve additional steps.  I have done a bit of Sed/Awk-ing, but was a good while ago.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of the shenanigans below are to deal with spaces in folder names, but I think this function will generate your output...

Usage: `countsubdirs PUT/PATH/HERE`

```
countsubdirs(){
    ORIGIFS=$IFS
    IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
    DIRS=$(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d )
    for D in $DIRS; do echo $D "=>" $(find $D -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l) subdirs; done
    IFS=$ORIGIFS
}
```

Output:

```
temp/hello =>        1 subdirs
temp/ntest 4 =>        0 subdirs
temp/temp =>        0 subdirs
temp/test =>        2 subdirs
temp/test 4 =>        0 subdirs
temp/test3 =>        1 subdirs
temp/tester =>        0 subdirs
temp/xl =>        1 subdirs
```

Comment: Assuming that this is meant to be a shell script, I got it working!  Thanks!  I made a minor modification:  I changed the 'dirs' variable you set to look like this:  "DIRS=$(find . -name TOC )".   Maybe not as sexy as doing an Awk/Sed combo, but it worked well.  :)

Comment: As long as it works, I'm all for it. Yes, it is a shell function (like an extended alias). I find it easier to use than a shell script, because if you add those lines to `.bash_profile` then the command will be available in any terminal window. Glad you were able to edit it to fit your particular application. You might play with `printf` in place of `echo` if you want to get the output aligned... Finally, I wasn't sure if you only wanted immediate subdirectories or nested ones too, so this obviously does immediate only.

Comment: Immediate only was the intent.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do

```
for d in ./*/*/*/*/*/subfolder; do
    printf "%s\t" "$d"
    find "$d" -type d -printf "%i\n" | wc -l
done
```

The `-printf` option to the `find` command is a safeguard in case you have directory names with newlines or whatever.

Comment: @nyxee "Didn't work" how? The wildcard certainly loops over all matching directories and the `find | wc` certainly counts directories within each match. Perhaps you need a different wildcard in your case?